# Warning: Unused local variable. (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _charity.call{value: msg.value}("");

Tags: solidity

```
contracts/Test.sol:128:21: Warning: Unused local variable.
(bool sent, bytes memory data) = _charity.call{value: msg.value}("");
^---------------^
```

```
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _charity.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(sent, "DONATION_FAILED");
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the warning says, you have declared a variable that you're not using later.

Your code shows using `sent`, which leaves `data` as the unused variable. If you're not planning to use it, you can remove the declaration to resolve the warning.

```
// removed the declaration of `data`
(bool sent,) = _charity.call{value: msg.value}("");
require(sent, "DONATION_FAILED");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's worked